# How to change the default set to open database files as text in Device File Explorer in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When the first time I tried opening my database file in my Device file explorer, there was a dialog which asked whether to open as a file or choose some other program to open.

I do have SQLite browser. But, first time by mistake I opened the database file as text and everytime after that after clicking the file its taking it as default.

Can anyone help me and suggest how to change the default set?

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]>  Following are steps you can follow.

> 1. Right click on file.
> 2. Open with
> 3. Choose another app
> 4. more apps
> 5. select the sqlite browser
> 6. check box "Always use this app to open this file"
>
> You are done. Thanks

[image]
 [image]
[image: l]

Comment: There is no "open with" option, only open n after clicking open it opens as some jumbled text in android studio

Comment: can you share screenshot of while right clicking on file

Comment: check the above image

Comment: Ok so you are going to the computer's file structure and opening that specific file? But is there no option to do it in Android Studios device file explorer? I will try to share the screenshot, need some tim

Comment: Check images. I added step by step images. I performed it on my side. It is working.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mirza saab Thanx a lot

Comment: No problem bro.. I am happy and satisfied it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the file you want to change it’s opening type
Then : click on file > select : Associate with file type...
And then you can change to any file you want

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try change the registered file patterns in your settings:

[image: Screenshot of InteliJ Settings > Editor > File Types]

Comment: Thanks man. Actually i need to open .plist in android studio. i accidentally set it to open in xcode.